# Showing 1 Minute increments in time field with Sharepoint 2013 list

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, date-time

My company requires our list drop downs to contain time in 1 minute increments. Is there an OOB option I can update to change this?

If not, are there any options without installing a third party solution for accomplishing this? Detailed instructions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry can you please explain a bit further?

Comment: When adding a DateTime field to a Custom List within SharePoint, the Time portion of the field has a drop down in the minutes section, only showing 5 minute increments. I am tasked to have a list that will show 1 minute increments in this field. Is there a way to change the field to show 1 minute increments with out of the box options? If not, is there a way to change the drop down for minutes to 1 minute increments with custom coding? If so, could I please have detailed instructions on how to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up having to do was creating a Date field, then creating a Choice field for Hour including values 0 - 23, and a Choice field for Hour including values 0 - 59. Then creating a custom New Form and manipulating the table to place the Minute and Hour fields next to the date field. It now looks like a DateTime field, but with 1 minute increments.

Answer (score 0):

For Sharepoint 2007 was the solution  -  customize New/Edit forms in SharePoint Designer - remove default form, add new item from and change the DateTime field control type from  "list form field" to "TextBox"

Here details:

http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.ru/2011/06/sharepoint-edit-date-and-time-in-one.html

Comment: Ruslan, This option only works, as it states, by disabling attachments. We need attachments enabled in this case. Any other solutions out there?

Comment: I don't think that disable attachment is actually required. The real idea of the solution - change the field formatting method in sharepoint designer from complicated control to simple one. And, if you need, append to it any external javascript datetime picker. Disadvantage of the method - pour scalability - you have to make changes manually.

Comment: In this solution does it allow the user to have a drop down with increments of one minute? Or is the solution to change the drop down to a free text field?

Comment: it is a solution to change the drop down to a free text field

Comment: This causes another issue for entry errors. Is there no solution to change the drop down values to 0-59 instead of the 15 minute increments?

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to get 1 minute intervals in your column without messing about with multiple columns and calculated views, is to use InfoPath.

Open up InfoPath Designer, using the Sharepoint List template, then select your List URL to update existing list, then when the form template opens, edit the time field to a type of 09:46 or 09:46 AM, whichever is your preference.

Publish the InfoPath form and you'll be able to go to the list, add or edit and new item and enter your desired minute.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry, the tag was for SharePoint-Foundation, thus I do not have access to InfoPath. Otherwise, this is a great option. Thanks